# GPUImage transform filter and blending mode cause line artifacts?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am transforming a texture and then applying a blend filter with that resized texture. When I do that I sometimes get a little line showing the outline of the transformed/blended texture. I'm guess this is because the transform rescales the texture to a half pixel or something? Any ideas?

Here's a link to an image that shows a black line above the text "legit":
[image: http://mysti.ch/images/transform_line.png]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was also inverting the color of the texture, then applying the transform, and then applying the blend... I changed it so that it applied the transform, then inverted the color, and then blended and the strange line went away.